# Changing pointer type causes write access exception

Tags: c, pointers, memory, allocation

I'm trying to figure out whether writing a block of memory near the end of a buffer will overflow, but I'm running into a weird problem which I guess is due to some misunderstanding on how types for pointers work.

Given this code, which just allocates memory and tries to write at the very end of it:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
    size_t size = 19200;
    int16_t* start = (int16_t*) VirtualAlloc(0, size, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
    int16_t* end = start + size;
    int16_t* writeToEnd = end - sizeof(int16_t);
    *writeToEnd = 1;

    return 0;
}
```

I get a illegal write exception at `writeToEnd`. However if I change everything to `int`:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
    size_t size = 19200;
    int* start = (int*) VirtualAlloc(0, size, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
    int* end = start + size;
    int* writeToEnd = end - sizeof(int);
    *writeToEnd = 1;

    return 0;
}
```

Everything works fine. I would understand if some of the values would cause the `int16_t`-type to overflow, but by checking all the values manually everything seems OK.
Visual Studio memory window shows the available memory being smaller than what `end` calculates to.

What am I misunderstanding? Shouldn't `pointer + size == endOfBuffer`, regardless of type used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter in VirtualAlloc is the size to be allocated in **bytes**. If you want an array of 19200 16-bit integers, you should call it

```
int16_t* start = (int16_t*) VirtualAlloc(0, size*sizeof(int16_t), MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
```

then the next line is ok:

```
int16_t *end = start + size;
```

As here you are effectively getting

```
int16_t *end = &start[size];
```

which is 19200*2 bytes ahead of start.

Pointer arithmetic uses the number of elements to skip, not number of bytes. Adding 1 to an int32_t* skips 4 bytes, adding 1 to an int16_t* skips 2 bytes.

I don't know why the int case is working for you, as it shouldn't.

Comment: Well spotted. The reason why the second is working is probably due to page rounding strategy by VirtualAlloc() and is landing on an page owned by the same process, which is even worse than a crash.

Comment: Thank you, the `int`-version working really threw me off. However, how would I get the actual boundary if I truly wanted a 19200-byte buffer? Any easier way than `int16_t start* = (int16_t*)((char*)start + size)`?

Comment: The last position is char *last = ((char *) start) + size - 1; If your objective is to write a byte 1 at the last available byte, you should not do that with anything wider than a byte, or the results will vary according to the endianess of the computer (in little endian architectures int16_t i=1 will be written as 0x01 0x00, on big endian architectures it will be written 0x00 0x01).